# How to execute performance tests for web pages that need authentication

Tags: jmeter

How do I test web pages for which you need to perform some sort of authentication beforehand? For example, a web page https://example.com/orders can only be accessed if there is a JWT in the browser's local storage (assuming it's a client application such as Angular).

I have watched several videos about people using JMeter to test web pages, but all the examples that they have used are public web pages (e.g. https://google.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different authentication types, the most common is via [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and it's being handled automatically in JMeter via [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

When it comes to [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction) after successful authentication you should get a [JWT token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-1), it can be extracted from the response using a suitable Post-Processor and then for subsequent requests you can add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) to send the token via [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header.

Comment: We are not using Cookies though. We are storing the JWT in the browser's local storage and using that to invoke back-end APIs. I guess what I'm really trying to ask is, what is the principle behind load testing frameworks like Angular? 

If a web page needs to get data on the server to render them in a <table> element, a proper result is an HTML that contains a table, correct? But if we load test an Angular web page, we get an HTML with <app-root></app-root> instead. I don't know if we are doing the right thing.

Comment: back-end API doesn't have access to the browser's local storage, the token is passed from the storage via [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), you need to figure out how does the browser do it and [implement the same in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser). Be aware that JMeter is not a browser hence it doesn't have local storage, you will need to handle it a little bit differently

Comment: If I understand what you are saying is correct, then it's technically not possible to test web pages for which the token is stored in the local storage.